# ¿Cómo calcular días después a una fecha en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito que muestre:

> **código de orden**, **fecha de orden**, **fecha requerida** y **posible fecha de envío**

A todas las órdenes que no tengan fecha de envío ¿cómo puedo calcular la posible fecha de envío que debe calcularse con 15 días después de la fecha requerida?

Tengo la siguiente sintaxis:

```
Select OrderID, OrderDate, RequiredDate from orders;
```

Comment: eso se hace con `date_add()`

Comment: Gracias, lo estoy tratando de armar pero no lo logro Select OrderID, date_add(RequiredDate + 15) OrderDate, RequiredDate 
from orders me puede orientar en este caso por favor

Comment: ok, es algo sencillo, me extraña que aun no te hayan respondido, dame un momento.

Comment: intenta con `Select OrderID, date_add(RequiredDate, INTERVAL 15 DAY) OrderDate, RequiredDate from orders`

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que intentas obtener deberías ocupar:

- `ADDDATE` para agregar un intervalo de tiempo
- Como tratas de agregar un período de 15 días entonces usa `INTERVAL 15 DAY`
- Indicas que solo se aplique el incremento de días cuando no se tenga fecha de envío en las órdenes, pudieras entonces usar `IS NULL` en conjunto con `WHERE`

Tal vez de este modo:

```
Select OrderID, 
       OrderDate, 
       ADDDATE(RequiredDate, INTERVAL 15 DAY) AS Fecha
from orders
WHERE fechaenvio* IS NULL;
```

Indicando que solo aplique ese incremento de 15 días *DONDE* la fecha de envío este `NULL`

> *Solo sustituye `fechaenvio` por el nombre de la columna que aplique para tu escenario.